# remix two function from receiving commands in two table and make two functions to be one only

Tags: python, if-statement, sqlite

I have tried to write a if statement to combine two functions into one
but it 's not working .
These two functions has no any errors and my teammate needs me to combine two functions into one and receive two table 's field in one function.
before the functions(receiving two table's field for each function):

```
def readrouter(x):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return read;

a = input("x:")
for result in readrouter(a):
    print (result[0])

# def readswitch(x):
#         conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
#         cur = conn.cursor()
#         cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,))
#         read = cur.fetchall()
#         return read;
#
# a = input("x:")
# for result in readswitch(a):
#     print (result[0])
```

After i follow some if statement and write new one:

```
# def readciscodevice(x):
#         var = 1
#         conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
#         cur = conn.cursor()
#         if var == 1:
#                 cur.execute(
#                         "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
#                         (x,))
#                 read = cur.fetchall()
#                 return read
#         else:
#                 cur.execute(
#                         "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
#                         (x,))
#                 read = cur.fetchall()
#                 return read;
#
#
# a = input("x:")
# for result in readciscodevice(a):
#         print(result[0])
```

I could draw my commands in switch 's table
but cant receive any commands from table's router
Any one help me to correct my if-statement's mistake?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `readciscodevice` function is not using the `x` parameter to decide which part of the `if` statement to run, it is using the `var` variable instead, which is always set to `1`
You need to change your if statement to say

```
if x == 1:
```

then it should work.

A few other comments:

You should remove the `var` variable altogether, since it serves no purpose.

You should also pick a better name for `x` (for example `useSwitch`), and make sure you pass in a boolean value (True\False) rather than a number.

You could abbreviate the `if` statement to just say:

```
if useSwitch:
```

Comment: i will honor you after 3mins :)